# How to check for a click an ImageView or a Gallery which is in a custom listView?

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have two custom `ListViews`. One of them consists of an `ImageView` and `TextViews` in each item. The other one consists of a `Gallery` and a `TextView`. When I click `ImageView` I want a bigger version of that picture to appear on the screen. For the gallery the when I click an item of that `Gallery`, a `Gallery` will appear on the screen with bigger versions of the pictures.

I can get the position of the clicked item in `ListView` with `onItemClickedListener`. However, I cannot understand either `TextView` or `ImageView` clicked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {` of your CoustomAdapter

```
TextView tv=convertView.findViewById(R.id.yourTexView);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO What ever you want

            }
        });
```